# How to change the font color of an attribute field using attribute table?

Tags: python, qgis-3

I'm using QGIS 3.0.1 and I would like to change the font color of some attribute fields with a changing value in attribute table (depends on which value was entered). My idea is to use signal "attributeValueChanged" but I can't find any information about how I can change font color or how I can access it via python. Does QGIS 3.0.1 / Python support something like this or rather not?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to do it with python programming only ? if not using the conditional formatting button (last button on top of attribute table) do the trick

Comment: I work on a plugin and I would like to do it in python. Is it possible to define the conditional formatting in python?

Comment: Yes, you can define conditional formatting using the Python API. Have a look to https://qgis.org/api/classQgsConditionalLayerStyles.html I will try later an answer

Answer (score 2):

Thats my code how it works for me for a very simple case.

```
    if self.isSupported(aLayer):
     provider = aLayer.dataProvider()
     columns = provider.fields()
     for c in columns:
      name = str(c.name())
      c_styles = aLayer.conditionalStyles()
      f_styles = c_styles.fieldStyles(name)
      list = []
      style1 = QgsConditionalStyle("@value = 'invalid'")
      color = QColor(255,0,0)
      style1.setTextColor(color)
      list.append(style1)
      c_styles.setFieldStyles(name, list)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the colour of label text by attribute using data defined override on 'color'. For example this expression works for me in QGIS 3:

```
CASE
 WHEN "local_type" = 'Town' THEN color_rgb(255,0,0)
 WHEN "local_type" = 'City' THEN  color_rgb(34,139,34)
 WHEN "local_type" = 'Village' THEN  color_rgb(0,0,205)
ELSE  color_rgb(80, 80, 80) END
```

How you would go about changing the attribute is not something I can help you with I'm afraid.